# DevExpress WPF ChartControl add vertical line that can be dragged and saved for a series

Tags: wpf, charts, devexpress

I have a **ChartControl** that contains some **LineSeries2D**. The line series are generated dinamically. Is there an easy way to add a vertical line that can be dragged across the chart. So this vertical line is only visible if the mouse is in drag mode and the drag operation has to be started from the left margin of the chart. Also when I release the mouse inside the chart the vertical line will be saved there and I want the posibility to reposition that line in the future by dragging it. Are there options that can be set in XAML to quickly achive this behavior. If not, how could I implement this behavior for a **WPF** DevExpress ChartControl

Comment: Did you ever implement a solution for this? I was just discussing the possibility of implementing this functionality with a coworker...

Comment: Nope, we dropped this functionality.